# Getting a compile error in c# about not referencing System.XML, yes System.XML is being reference

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I am trying to add a new feature to an old program I wrote. However, when trying to get the program to build in VS express it spits back an error message to me.

> Error 1   The type 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\Path\To\File\summaryForm.cs  101 18
>   SerialController

However the thing is at the top of the cs file, it has

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.Xml;
```

Any ideas whyits not recognizing the XML reference?

Comment: You have the proper using statement, but do you actually have a reference to the System.Xml dll in your project references?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using a namespace does not mean you referenced something. You need to *add a reference* to `System.XML`.

If you are using Visual Studio, right click on references, click *Add Reference* and then select `System.XML`.

Answer (score 11):

[The `using` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) (not to be confused with [the `using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)) is just to import namespaces from your referenced assemblies into your code file in order to make it easier to use the types that the assemblies contain without having to fully-qualify their names with their namespaces.  The fact that the assembly `System.Xml` and the namespace `System.Xml` are named the same, in this case, is merely a coincidence.

You need to actually add the `System.Xml.DLL` reference, as it suggests, to your project: right-click on "References" beneath your project in the solution explorer, select "Add Reference", then locate and check off the `System.Xml` assembly within the list of framework assemblies:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `using` *directive*. There are two unrelated features in C# that both use the keyword `using`. They are the [`using` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) and the [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). Using the name of the second when you mean the first can only lead to confusion.

Comment: A `using` does not really import an assembly, but a namespace.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus -- You're right, of course.  Updated.

Answer (score 4):

The error may be misleading if you have the reference - you may also need to reference `System.Xml.Serialization`.

[image: System.Xml.Serialization library]