# Trouble with System.Xml library

Tags: c#, libraries

Getting the pretty common error

*"The type 'XmlReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'*

Here is the line that the error references to

```
SecurityToken securityToken = tokenHandler.ReadToken(contextTokenString)
```

Yes, I've seen this question a lot of times there (adding System.Xml to the assembly solves the problem for everyone), the clue is **I DO** have System.Xml dll in my references assembly and I did import the System.Xml namespace.

Can anyone help me?

P.S.: I am sorry for my English, there might be some mistakes :P

Comment: What version of net library is your project set for?  If you are set for Net 2.0 the xml library will not work.

Comment: It seems like the System.Xml isn't actually included as Intellisence doesn't suggest System.Xml while I type "using System."

Comment: It works fine in other projects tho

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove reference to `System.Xml`
2. Add reference back to `System.Xml`
3. In *References* node in *Solution Explorer*, right-click on `System.Xml.dll` and click on *properties*
4. See what's the value of `Copy Local`. If it's `True`, change it to `False`, clean and rebuild the solution (or even restart VS). If it's `False`, change it to `True`, clean and rebuild (and/or restart VS), and change it again to `False` and clean and rebuild. It should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look if the project is indeed in .NET 4.0  maybe it changed

The dll is probably from another .NET version.  I would try removing it and reference it again

Comment: I would also check if System.Xml.Serialization is there as well.  And here's a reference that could help :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835615/getting-a-compile-error-in-c-sharp-about-not-referencing-system-xml-yes-system

Comment: Kind of duplicate here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957617/xmlreader-is-declared-in-a-different-assembly-even-though-system-xml-is-referenc

Comment: The project is in .NET 4.5.2

Comment: System.Xml.Serialization is included too

Comment: Here you go.  I would suggest  @Javad_Amiry idea

Answer (score 0):

See the error message and as it says it's expecting a `Version=4.0.0.0`. Since you say that you have referenced and imported the namespace then check the version of the referenced dll, it's definitely a different version.

Comment: Checked it too, it is  4.0.0.0